# Explain why the area inside the curve will be given by the following formulas

Tags: calculus

[image]

As $ \ t \ $ varies from $ \ 0 \ $ to $ \ 2 \pi \ $ the above curve plots out in counterclockwise manner with no segment repeated.

Explain why the area inside the curve will be given by the following formulas :

$ - \int_{0}^{2 \pi} y(t) x'(t) dt=96.2113 \ $

and

$ \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{2} (r(t))^2 dt=96.2113 \ $

**Answer:**

The equation of the curve is $ \ r(t)=8 \cos (3t) \ , \ 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi \ $

For polar curve , we have the area formula

$ area=\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{2} r(t)^2 dt \ $

But why the $ \ -\int_0^{2 \pi} y(t) x'(t) dt \ $ also give the area ?

**Help me explaining the second one.**

Comment: Use `\approx` instead of `=` to get $\approx$.

Comment: my question is why $ \ - \int_0^{2 \pi} y(t) x'(t) dt \ $ gives the area inside the curve ? Would  you explain it ?

Comment: See [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArea.aspx) for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas in question come from [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem): Let $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ be a bounded region in the plane with piecewise $C^1$ boundary $\partial \Omega$, oriented such that $\Omega$ is to the left of $\partial\Omega$. Furthermore, let ${\bf F}=\bigl(P(x,y),Q(x,y)\bigr)$ be a $C^1$ vector field defined in some neighborhood of  $\Omega$. Then
$$\int_{\partial\Omega} {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf z}=\int_\Omega{\rm curl}({\bf F})\>{\rm d}(x,y)\ ,$$
in other terms:
$$\int_{\partial\Omega} Pdx+Qdy=\int_{\Omega}(Q_x-P_y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)\ .\tag{1}$$
If we now choose $(P,Q)$ such that $Q_x-P_y\equiv1$ then we obtain on the RHS of $(1)$ just the desired area of $\Omega$. One possible way is choosing $P(x,y)\equiv0$, $Q(x,y)=x$. Plugging this into $(1)$ we obtain
$${\rm area}(\Omega)=\int_{\partial\Omega}x\>dy\ .$$
Similarly for the two other formulas. This method of calculating areas is very handy when the domain $\Omega$ is not given by inequalities, but by specifying the occurring boundary arcs.

Answer (score 1):

It is the simple chain rule.  The formula for area is normally: $\int y dx$.  However, since y is given as a function of "t" we may write, $\int y dx=\int y\frac{dx(t)} {dt} dt=\int yx'(t)dt$, with the usual change of variable rule.

Comment: why $ \ - \ $ sign is taken in front of the integration ?

Comment: You need to be careful about what substitution you make as some substitutions (function of functions etc) will reverse the increment ("dx vs dt") of the integration.